# Is there a faster way to iterate through a grid horizontally (bottom left to top right)?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, stringbuilder

I have been given a `String[][]` and I'm trying to add all the elements that are present horizontally from bottom left to top right of my grid into a stringbuilder.

Here is my code:

```
public class prac5 {
    public static String slanting(String[][] a){
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (int x = 0; x < a.length; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < a[0].length; y++){
                s.append(a[x + 1][y + 1]);
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(s);
    }
}
```

I was wondering that is there any way to reduce the time complexity in doing this task, while also providing the right output as stated above?

Comment: The time complexity is already O(n).

Comment: You might be able to achieve a slight performance advantage using multiple StringBuilders and multiple threads to process all rows at the same time; this might make this marginally faster - but much more complicated due to Thread coordination.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I have never used that before, could you please show me how to do so?